# Error saving a list of items when first item have entity validation error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, validation

I have a generic business class that I use to manipulate my data with mysql 5.6 and the entity framework 6. I created a method that imports data from a table and create a list of objects so I can call the business class and save or update the records in the target database.

```
//part of import method
using (var business = new Business<Customer>(context))
{
    foreach (var sourceCustomer in sourceCustomersList)
    {
        var customer = business.GetData().ToList().Find(x=>x.OriginalId == sourceCustomer.Id) ?? new Customer();

        customer.Name = sourceCustomer.Name; // for example, this property is required
        customer.Fone = sourceCustomer.Fone;
        customer.City = sourceCustomer.City;
        customer.State = sourceCustomer.State);
        customer.Active = sourceCustomer.Active;

        if (customer.Id > 0)
        {
            business.Update(Customer);
        }
        else
        {
            customer.SourceId = sourceCustomer.Id;
            business.Insert(fornecedor);
        }
    }
}


public class Business<T> : IBusiness<T>, IDisposable
{
    protected ESistemContext Context;

    public Business(ESistemContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public virtual bool Insert(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }



    public virtual bool Update(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Context == null)
            return;
        Context.Dispose();
        Context = null;
    }
}
```

My problem is: when I have a validation error on an item (null value for Name property), all other items that I try to process after have the same validation error (even they have a Name property correctly filled) when calls context.SaveChanges() the business class calling an exception and shows the same validation error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the welcome @NathanTuggy . I removed the methods used in other parts of the application. Also removed the transaction control, even without him the error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching a lot, found the solution to the problem. Added the following line of code in the catch block and the context now releases the entry to a new value and then make a new validation.

```
Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```